# Limit of $s_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$

Tags: limits, summation, radicals

\begin{align*}S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\end{align*}

how to calculate the limit $s_n$?

\begin{align*}\lim_{n\to \infty } \, S_n\end{align*}

Comment: What is the question you are trying to ask? What thoughts do you have about the problem you are trying to address? Please edit your post heavily to put it into proper question form (including your own input on the problem and issues you may be facing).

Comment: $\displaystyle{\Large 2\ ?}$.

Comment: Can one add an answer via using stolz?

Comment: @polynomial If you prefer an answer based on some specific method, I'll suggest you include that preference into your question.

Comment: The Maple command $$limit((sum(1/sqrt(k), k = 1 .. n))/sqrt(n), n = infinity) $$ outputs 2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the curve $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. We have
$$\int_1^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\lt 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lt \int_0^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx.$$
Evaluate the integrals. We get 
$$2\sqrt{n+1}-2\lt  1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lt 2\sqrt{n}.$$
Divide everything by $\sqrt{n}$, and use **Squeezing** to conclude that our limit is $2$.

Comment: Thanks. I have trouble with constants, basically pay no attention to them. Works well, except when it doesn't.

Comment: You must be a measure theorist ;)

Comment: No, just have taught too many calculus courses. But I am estimation-inclined.

Answer (score 10):

An answer using the Stolz–Cesàro theorem: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ \sum_{k=1}^n 1/\sqrt{k} }{\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/\sqrt{n} }{\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{n-1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1} }{\sqrt{n}}=2.$$

Answer (score 9):

Since $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \ge \frac{2}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k+1}} = 2(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}) \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

We find.
$$\begin{align}
& \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \ge 2\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}) = 2(\sqrt{n+1}-1) \ge 2\sqrt{n} - 2\\
\text{and}\quad & \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \le 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}) = 2\sqrt{n} - 1
\end{align}
$$
As a result,
$$2 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}} \le S_n \le 2 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
\quad\implies\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = 2$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
{1 \over \sqrt{n}}\,\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \sqrt{k\,}}
&=
{1 \over \sqrt{n}}\,\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \sqrt{n\xi_{k}\,}}\,n\Delta\xi
=
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \sqrt{\xi_{k}\,}}\,\Delta\xi
\sim
\int_{1/n}^{1}{{\rm d}\xi \over \xi^{1/2}}
=
\left.\vphantom{\LARGE A}\;2\xi^{1/2}\right\vert_{1/n}^{1}
\\[3mm]&=
2\left(1 - {1 \over \sqrt{n\,}}\right)
=
2 - {2 \over \sqrt{n\,}} \to \color{#ff0000}{\Large 2}
\quad\mbox{when}\quad
n \to \infty
\end{align}