# What is the limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}+\sqrt{2k+1}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}\right)=? $$

I tried with the squeeze theorem, though I got the upper bound, but I couldn't find the lower bound. I also tried to solve it with the order limit theorem, but without any success. I guessed the result should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. How can I do this?

Comment: Possibly a Riemann sum?

Comment: In general, if the sum can't be conveniently calculated, as Jack D'Aurizio and Yash Malik did below, such sequence calls for the [Stolz-Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) (a very similar example is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/495056/265976)), a discrete version of l'Hôpital's rule.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is a telescopic sum in disguise. Since:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}\right)\tag{1}$$
by summing $(1)$ for $k$ that goes from $1$ to $n$ we have:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1}} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{1}\right)\tag{2}$$
hence by multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and taking the limit as $n\to +\infty$ we clearly have:
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1}}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: (+1) I was reading the preceding answers and couldn't believe that no one saw that the series telescoped. Glad to see yours.

Comment: This is why they always tell you in school to rationalize your denominators :)

Answer (score 13):

Hint 1:
$\frac{1}{\sqrt1+\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3-\sqrt1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt3+\sqrt5}=\frac{\sqrt5-\sqrt3}{2}$

and so on, so you are left with $\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-1}{2}$ inside the brackets,
hope you can do it from here now.

Hint 2:  (see only if you need it)

> After multiplying by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ it becomes $\frac{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}{2}.   $ Now what is $\frac 1n$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ if $n \to{+ \infty}$?

Comment: There were some little mistakes, so I corrected them. Also some formatting changes to make it more concise. Hope you don't make, but feel free to change back, if you do.

Comment: @eudes thnx    for the edit

Answer (score 7):

**Other hint.**

For $n \in \mathbb N$ and $x \in [n,n+1]$ you have $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2x+1}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}} \le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2x-3}}$$ which enables to compare the sum with integrals.

Comment: How would it help to know the range of each term when what you want to do is to calculate an exact value? Could you please expand on this hint?

Comment: Because if you compute RHS and LHS and divides by $\sqrt{n}$, both sides have the same limit.

Answer (score 4):

Notice, we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 1+\sqrt 3}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt {2n-1}+\sqrt {2n+1}}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {2r-1}+\sqrt {2r+1}}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\left(\frac{\sqrt {2r+1}-\sqrt {2r-1}}{2r+1-(2r-1)}\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt {2r+1}-\sqrt {2r-1}}{\sqrt n}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{2r}\left(1+\frac{1}{2r}\right)^{1/2}-\sqrt{2r}\left(1-\frac{1}{2r}\right)^{1/2}}{\sqrt n}$$
Using binomial expansion of $\left(1-\frac{1}{2r}\right)^{1/2}$ & neglecting higher power terms as $\left(\frac{1}{2r}\right)^2$, $\left(\frac{1}{2r}\right)^3,\ldots $

$$=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt r}{\sqrt n} \left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2r}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2r}\right)\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt r}{\sqrt n} \left[\frac{1}{2r}\right]$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt {nr}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sqrt {\frac{r}{n}}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt {x}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}[2\sqrt x]_{0}^{1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}[2-0]$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$$

Comment: Such an expensive solution for such a simple problem!

Comment: @Jack: Yes and no -- it may seem gratuitous to someone just learning the material, but once this stuff becomes old-hat, it is often an easier and faster method to solve a problem than the "simple" solution.

Comment: It might be useful to give some explanation of why we can ignore the higher order terms of the binomial expansion.

Comment: @robjohn: This answer is completely wrong, especially so after his edit. $\frac{1}{2r}$ is **not very small** as it always starts from $r = 1$ in the sum! Moreover $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}$ cannot be thrown away just because $\frac{1}{n}$ is **so-called very small** for large $n$!

Comment: Alright, I edited to add explanation.

Comment: @Hurkyl: Please check before affirming that a method actually works. You cannot just perform binomial expansion of an expression within a **sum** and throw away terms just like that.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot: $\frac1r$ is not, of itself, small since $r$ ranges from $1$ upwards.  You are relying on the fact that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{r=1}^n\frac{\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{n}}\frac1{r^k}=0$ for $k\gt1$. This, at least, should be mentioned.

Comment: @user21820: Sure you can, if you recognize that the neglected terms don't affect the result. Yes, the minor details probably should have been spelled out in this particular setting as robjohn says, but that doesn't make the method *wrong*.

Comment: @Hurkyl: If you check the intermediate edit you will see that it was indeed an incorrect method. Of course when the steps are ambiguous one can always argue that the correct analysis was intended, but almost always students do not even know the correct analysis.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't spot that the series telescopes (and this is always worth a check - usually careful inspection of the first few terms will suffice) then here is a solution using the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Write the desired series as a fraction:

$$S_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k-1}+\sqrt{2k+1}}}{\sqrt{n}} = \frac{a_n}{b_n} $$

Now $b_n = \sqrt{n}$ is strictly monotone and divergent (since it is strictly increasing and $b_n \to +\infty$). We need this condition for Stolz–Cesàro to apply.

Now consider the "fraction of differences" (does it have a more technical name?):

$$\frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{b_n - b_{n-1}} = \frac{\left(\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}\right)^{-1}}{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}} = \frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n-1}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}}{\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{n}}}$$

The numerator $1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}} \to 2$ and the denominator $\sqrt{2+\frac{1}{n}}+\sqrt{2-\frac{1}{n}} \to 2\sqrt{2}$ so the fraction tends to $\frac{2}{2\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Then since $b_n$ was strictly monotone and divergent, and the limit of $\frac{a_n - a_{n-1}}{b_n - b_{n-1}}$ exists and equals $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, we can conclude from the Stolz–Cesàro theorem that the limit of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ also exists and also equals $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I have learned a new result, thank you. @silverfish