# prove that $2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)<1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< 2\sqrt{n}$

Tags: induction

prove $2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)<1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< 2\sqrt{n}$ by mathematical indcution.

my attempt:
we prove for $n=1$

for $n=1$ than $0.828<1<2$ so true for $n=1$

we assume that this is true for $n=k$

ie  $2\sqrt{k+1}-1<1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}< 2\sqrt{k}$

Now we have to prove for $n=k+1$

consider $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}< 2\sqrt{k}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\leq 2\sqrt{k}+1<2\sqrt{k+1}$  Is this correct?

what about otherside

Comment: @JitendraSingh..let me see first

Comment: @JitendraSingh..im asking how can we prove by using induction

Comment: Not correct since squaring both sides gives the following: $$2\sqrt k + 1 < 2 \sqrt{k+1} \\ 
4k+4\sqrt{k} + 1 < 4k+4 \\
\sqrt{k} < \frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: When you say *is this correct*... I prefer to revert the question to you: *have you proven that $2 \sqrt{k} + 1 \lt 2 \sqrt{k+1}?$* What makes you think that the inequality is valid?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos..almost similar problem.sir

Answer (score 2):

(Using mathematical induction),

(As you did) Now we assume that this is true for $n=k$, i.e.

$$2\sqrt{k+1}-1<1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}< 2\sqrt{k}\tag 1$$

Now we have to prove for $n=k+1$. All you have to do is to prove

$$2\sqrt{k+2}-1<2\sqrt{k+1}-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\tag 2$$
and
$$2\sqrt k+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<2\sqrt{k+1}\tag 3$$

To prove $(2)$,
$$2\sqrt{k+2}-2\sqrt{k+1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{k+2}+\sqrt{k+1}}<\frac{2}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$
Therefore $(2)$ is true.

To prove $(3)$,
$$2\sqrt{k+1}-2\sqrt k=\frac2{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt k}>\frac2{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt {k+1}}=\frac1{\sqrt {k+1}}$$
Therefore $(3)$ is true.

Now from $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$, the equation for $n=k+1$ also holds.

Answer (score 1):

Use the condiction from $n=k$ and what we should get is that $$2\sqrt{k+2}-1<\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}}_{>2\sqrt{k+1}-1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$     So we just have to compare $2\sqrt{k+2}-1$ with $2\sqrt{k+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}-1 $
$$(2\sqrt{k+2} )^2=4(k+2)$$
$$(2\sqrt{k+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}})^2=4(k+1)+4+\frac{1}{k+1}=4(k+2)+\frac{1}{k+1}>(2\sqrt{k+2})^2 $$
$$\Rightarrow$$
$$ 2\sqrt{k+2}-1< 2\sqrt{k+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}-1$$
So wir have
$$2\sqrt{k+2}-1< 2\sqrt{k+1}-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the curve $y=\frac 1{\sqrt x}$ and divide the interval $(0,n+1)$ into rectangles of unit length. We have
$$\int_1^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\lt 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lt \int_0^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$
Evaluate the integrals, and we have tthe required proof
$$2(\sqrt{n+1}-1)<1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< 2\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: This is almost exactly [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/495039/752069) of the answers that are linked in the comments. Please, try to avoid rewriting the ideally same answers. To do this, take a quick look at the links that are shared in the comments claiming that the post is duplicate.

Comment: @VIVID Sorry, the comment came while I was typing my answer out. That's why I missed the comment.